# WooCoomerce add to cart button with quantity selector in home page with Ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to display add to cart button and quantity selector with ajax for each product in home or any custom page that shows products.
this is my first code:

```
    <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); 
        global $product;

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
             sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="button %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
            esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
            esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
            esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
            $product->is_purchasable() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
            esc_attr( $product->get_type() ),
            esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
            ),
            $product );                     

    ?>
```

this code display add to cart button for each product but without quantity selector and ajax.